# jQuery traversing the DOM - locating item by class when button clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**I don't have ID's to look at since some rows are inserted dynamically via clone.**

I'm looking for the value of the systemname which corresponds to the Check System button is clicked.

Here is the function:

```
function getSystemInfo(btn){    
    var buttonClicked = $(btn);
    var firstSystemName = buttonClicked.parent().next().find($("input.systemname"));
    alert( $(firstSystemName).val() );
}
```

Here is the generated source code:

```
<div name="singleSystemDiv" class="offset-bg">
    <div class="field inline">
    <label class="frmFlds_labels">System Name</label>
    <input name="systemname" class="systemname" size="15" value="d1cti1d4" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field inline">
    <label class="frmFlds_labels">Location</label>
        <select id="location" name="location">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Akron">Akron</option>
            <option value="Allen">Allen DC - Mob</option>
            <option value="Alpharetta">Alpharetta - Mob</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field inline">
    <label class="frmFlds_labels">Platform</label>
        <select id="platform" name="platform" onChange="updateModels(this);" class="platform">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="IBM" selected="selected">AIX</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input value="Remove System" onClick="removeSystemRow(this);" type="button">
        <input value="Check System" onClick="getSystemInfo(this);" type="button">
    </div>
</div>
```

The way I have this written, my alert is firing, undefined.

I seem to have to ask a lot of SO questions regarding traversing.  If anyone has a web site that demonstrates this, please post that.  jQuery's docs regarding .next(), parents(), etc, aren't doing it for me.

Comment: after seeing the answer by Rory, I see my function didn't go to the right parent level.  I needed to go higher.  I'll need to look into .closest() a bit more.  Thanks Rory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getSystemInfo(btn){    
    var buttonClicked = $(btn);
    var $firstSystemName = buttonClicked.closest("div[name='singleSystemDiv']").find($("input.systemname"));
    alert($firstSystemName.val());
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/reyXB/)

Alternatively, you could use `buttonClicked.parent().parent().find($("input.systemname"));` but I personally find chained `parent()` calls a bit ugly.

Comment: don't you think that `.closest(".offset-bg")` it's a little bit more readable?

Comment: SO wont let me mark this as correct yet.  I understand the solution now that it is done but I'm not sure I would have come up with .closest().

Comment: @Nicosunshine I do, however given that that classname is not semantic in anyway, I didn't want to rely on it always being on the correct div relative to the button.

Comment: With using closest, will this always search UP and not the next item in the loop?  The source code I posted could appear multiple times on the page.

Comment: @dlackey Yes, closest will always go up the DOM tree, and stop at the closest matching element, even if there are more than one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Fair enough :). @dlackey in this particular case, you could use `.parents` instead of closest and it'll work (the result set will be an array with every matched element and it'll be a little bit slower)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if closest goes up, is there something that searches down within the same parent?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - sorry to keep bugging you; I figured I go just go up to the current parent and back down until I hit the instance I'm looking for but I'm sure that takes some time was wondered if there was a more efficient way to do this.